# How Can I export the list of classes from a Visual studio 2008 solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vs-classview

Is there any easy way to get the list of classes from VS.Net 2008 to a  text file or an excel sheet.

I just want to make a list of classes that I have in a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In class view, Goto Class View Settings , Deselect all the unwanted items as per your need.

Select all the classes that you need. Now you can copy paste into any where.

Comment: I wish this worked in the Solution Explorer, so I could show my inheritance hierarchy and export it as text. (VS 2013 Professional)

Comment: @yoyo did you ever find a solution to that?

Comment: @yoyo I resolved to just picking through them myself. BUT I do know it probably wouldn't be hard to write some code which interacts with the treeview and extracts the contents. I just found it quicker to manually do it this time. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

1 possible way would be use find all (Ctrl Shift f is shortcut) within VS and search for Class and ser Look at these File Types as being *.cs and also for result options set "Display File names Only"