# Can Visual Studio export its "Class View" to plain text?

Tags: visual-studio, class, class-hierarchy

Can Visual Studio (2010 or 2012) export its "Class View" to plain text? I don't see any options or other way to do this except manually.

Are there any other tools for creating a plain text class view / hierarchy / list from code or Visual Studio projects?

What would be ideal would be exactly what I see in the "Class View" of Visual Studio with all items expanded, but in plain text.

Thanks!

Comment: No.  The source code that produced the info in the class view window is already in plain text.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm looking at a really large and complex project that spans multiple namespaces and wanted to get a good handle on where everything fits in; it would have been nice to export everything to plain text but if necessary I'll manually go through everything. Unfortunate.

Comment: This can be done with Copy & Paste. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3838615/16454