# C# Classes, export to Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, export-to-excel

Is it possible to export my classes to excel?

I need to have class name with all properties. I have Resharper and VS 2015 on my system.

I've searched this before and found this [How Can I export the list of classes from a Visual studio 2008 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838570/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-classes-from-a-visual-studio-2008-solution)
which is not my case.

I would prefer to have each class in a sheet and the properties as rows of the sheet if possible.

P.S: I know how to do it pro grammatically. I am looking for a way to do this simple task using Visual Studio. 
This is not the functionality of my project, so it is not a good idea

Comment: Could you describe the final formatting more? Do you want all the classes in a project as a spreadsheet, or each class as its own spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @IsaacvanBakel, Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these links
To get all classes :

[How to get all classes within namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace)

Get the property list from each class using **Reflaction**

[How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

After that search for export to excel.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I am not looking for a code to do that.

Comment: You can find it here in  Visual studio. go to the following menu option

Analyze > Calculate Code Metrics for Solution

It will show Code Metrics Result window. From this window choose export to excel and you'll get a report with all the projects, Namespaces, Classes, Methods and some other details about them in Excel file.

Comment: @MD's thanks. I mentioned your comment in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60867941/382515). If you want I delete it and you post your own.

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla u welcome no need to remove it... we are here to help not for so many rewards... :)